# JAVA: why binary literal for byte with negative sign is being considered as integer type?

Tags: java

I can't understand the following behavior.

I'm trying to declare byte mask using binary literal:

```
byte mask = 0b1111_1111;
```

But that's not possible, because I get the following error message:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte

The most interesting thing is that when I try to declare the mask directly, in decimal representation

```
byte mask = -1;
```

I get no error, but these two representations should be absolutely equal!

What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can safely assign a values  from `-2^7 to 2^7-1 (-128 to 127)` to a `byte` ,since it is 8 bits.

where as `0b1111_1111` = `255`

So need a cast there

```
 byte mask = (byte) 0b1111_1111;
```

Answer (score 4):

The value `0b1111_1111` is equal to 255, outside the `byte`'s range of `[-128, 127]`(because it is signed). Use:

```
byte mask=(byte)0b1111_1111&0xff;
```

The narrowing will remove the (all-zero) high bits and fit 8 into 8 without regard for sign.

Comment: How do you know that 0b1111_1111=255

Comment: @javaBeginner 1*2^0 + 1*2^1 + 1*2^2 + 1*2^3 + 1*2^4 + 1*2^5 + 1*2^6 + 1*2^7 = 255

Comment: @KirillSmirnov I know this if you want to convert from binary to decimal.But my query in 0b1111_1111 is what is the use "b" and underscore(_) here.

Comment: @javaBeginner "0b" is a prefix to specify a binary literal. And underscore is for comfortable reading only, it doesn't affect the code's execution, just for better vision.

Comment: @KirillSmirnov Thanks for the information,I was unaware of it

Answer (score 1):

Your "byte mask" is equivalent to `0xff` or `255`, which are too large to fit in an 8-bit signed `byte`, not `-1`, because the literal in the code is an `int`. If the value is within the range of a smaller type, the compiler can safely stuff it in there, but it can't safely assign a value outside the range `-128..127` to a `byte` variable, and you'll need a cast.

Comment: `0xFF` does fit in a byte, so that in itself is not the reason.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Not in Java, it doesn't. Trying to assign `0xff` to a `byte` results in a compile-time error of `possible loss of precision`.

Comment: You are missing my point, your post is confusing by saying it is "too large": the value 0xFF does fit - by definition - in a byte, that Java requires an explicit cast is to prevent errors because the literal `0xFF` in java is an int with value 255, not a byte with value -1, but the value in that byte after cast will still be 0xFF

Comment: @MarkRotteveel `0xff` may fit in a "byte", but it doesn't fit in a `byte`. I was careful to distinguish the Java primitive type from the common slang for "octet".

Comment: The int literal 0xff might not fit, but guess what `System.out.printf("%x%n", (byte)-1);` prints

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The fact that Java format strings go out of their way to print negative values in a friendly hex format when you use the `%x` conversion has nothing to do with the compiler and JVM's actual handling of the primitive type. Try talking to an embedded controller where you want to compose multiple `byte`s into an `int`.

Comment: I think you are confusing sign-extension when converting from signed byte to int with a 'different' storage for signed bytes.

Answer (score 1):

*All* numerical literals are considered as 'int', unless cast otherwise or they contain a decimal point or an 'e'.

Answer (score 1):

you can do type casting like this

```
    byte mask = (byte) 0b1111_1111;
```